# Code Help Array and Structure Variable in VB

Tags: vb.net

I don't know where to go from here. I think i have initialized a 2 dimensional array and populated it with User Input but I can't get it to average. So is there a way I can Average the rows of this array all separately?

Also If there is a better way to write this code to begin With any help would be great. I will also post the original Question at the bottom of the Code, Right out of the book.

```
Public Class frmMain

Structure TestScores
    Public decTest1 As Decimal
    Public decTest2 As Decimal
    Public decTest3 As Decimal
End Structure
Dim test(2) As TestScores
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    test(0).decTest1 = InputBox("Score 1:", "First Person")
    test(0).decTest2 = InputBox("Score 2:", "First Person")
    test(0).decTest3 = InputBox("Score 3:", "First Person")
    test(1).decTest1 = InputBox("Score 1:", "Second Person")
    test(2).decTest2 = InputBox("Score 2:", "Second Person")
    test(2).decTest3 = InputBox("Score 3:", "Second Person")
    test(3).decTest1 = InputBox("Score 1:", "Third Person")
    test(3).decTest2 = InputBox("Score 2:", "Third Person")
    test(3).decTest3 = InputBox("Score 3:", "Third Person")


End Sub

Private Function GetAverage(ByVal scores As TestScores) As Decimal
    ' calculates and returns the average score

    Dim decTotal As Decimal

    decTotal = scores.decTest1 + scores.decTest2 + scores.decTest3
    Return decTotal / 3
End Function

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub btnAverage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAverage.Click
    ' displays the average test score
    Dim max1 As Integer = 0
    Dim max2 As Integer = 0
    Dim max3 As Integer = 0

    max1 = (test(0) + test(1))

End Sub
```

End Class

**The Book Question:**
Open the Code Editor window. The btnAverage_Click procedure should declare a
three-element array of structure variables; each element will contain the test scores
for one student. The procedure should prompt the user for a student’s three test
scores and then store the scores in one of the structure variables in the array. It then
should use the function to determine the student’s average score. Finally, it should
display the student’s number (1, 2, or 3) along with the average score (formatted
with one decimal place) in the lblResult control. Save the solution and then start and
test the application. Figure 21-14 shows a sample run of the application when the
user enters the following scores: 100, 100, 100, 90, 85, 78, 73, 72, and 67. Close the
Code Editor window and then close the solution.

Comment: That's not technically a 2-d array. It's a single dimensional array of structs that happen to have three values.

Comment: Also, your book is a bit out-dated in teaching you to use variable prefixes. Modern style guidelines specifically recommend against them (with the exception that it's often useful to use them for different gui control types).

Comment: Where do you call your GetAverage method?

Answer (score 0):

A separate function shouldn't be necessary.  Just calculate the average on each element of the array,`max1 = (test(0).decTest1 + test(0).decTest2 + test(0).decTest3)\3`.

Since you declared max1 as integer I used integer division() which automatically formats the answer as an integer.